# STSdb: Store Custom Field Types

Tags: c#

### Background

I am trying to use STSdb to store custom types, such as `TimeSpan`. As soon as I initialize the `XTable`, however, the app crashes, due to `Appointment` having a non-supported `TimeSpan` object.

### Code

```
using (IStorageEngine engine = STSdb.FromFile("db.stsdb4"))
{
    // This statement immediately crashes the app.
    var table = engine.OpenXTable<string, Appointment>("Appointment");
}

class Appointment
{
    ...
    public TimeSpan Reminder { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### The Question

How can I get STSdb to recognize the `TimeSpan` object (or other custom types, for that matter)? Looking at [the custom comparer and persist logic docs](http://docs.stsdb.com/display/stsdb402/Custom+comparer+and+persist+logic), the custom record persist logic is added *after* the `engine.OpenXTable` statement...

And yes, I know I should have put STSdb as a tag, not as part of the title, but I don't have the 1500 rep required by SO to create a new tag -- and apparently no one else has used the STSdb tag before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official STSdb web site there is a Developer's Guide document that describes in detail key aspects of STSdb. You can find the STSdb 4.0.4 Developer's Guide here: [STSdb Documentation.](http://stsdb.com/stsdb-w4.0/resources/documentation/) 
The topic you are looking for is described on page 32 - "Custom XTable logic".

Answer (score 1):

STSdb now supports TimeSpan as a primitive type from version 4.0.4, released on 25.06.2014. You can find the release notes here: [STSdb 4.0.4 Release Notes.](http://stsdb.com/forum/general/announcements/453-stsdb-4-0-4-has-been-released.html)

Comment: +1 for the update, but do you know how I can get STSdb to recognize other object types, as per my original question?